# Why we are using ' : ' instead of ' ; ' in case control instruction?

Tags: c#, c, switch-statement, case-statement

I need to know why we are using colon on keyword `case` in c programming and not semicolon?

```
/*valid statement*/
case 1:
   do this;
case 2:
   do this;

/*why is invalid to write */

case 1;
    do this;
case 2;
    do this;
```

help me please

Comment: Because `case`s are labels and thats the syntaxis for labels.

Comment: Why case in `switch` why not in `if` and `else` condition?

Comment: Because this is not an instruction.

Comment: Early code was typeset using Gutenberg-style printing presses.  Programmers kept running out of `;` symbols, so they decided to switch to `:` for case statements so they could write longer programs.

Comment: @BJMyers not sure.  I heard that it was just a typo by Ritchie when documenting the language.

Comment: Why is this labeled C#? C and C# aren't even remotely the same language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why a `case` line shouldn't be ended with a semicolon**

In C-based languages, the semicolon has a specific function as the 'statement terminator'. This means that a semicolon marks the end of a specific statement of code, and the start of another. For more info on this see [this quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-C-statements-end-with-semicolons).

Therefore if you had a semicolon after each `case` line, the compiler would interpret them all as separate, individual statements. It would be like writing:

```
do case 1;
do this;
do case 2;
do this;
```

The compiler sees these as individual, 'normal' lines of code. It will probably then fail to compile, because the `case` keyword is specifically reserved only for use within `switch` statements.

---

As to why the `:` character was selected for this particular purpose: as Luca_65 mentioned the case is hiding a `goto` label statement. The colon is used in C to [label a section of code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c002fdz.aspx), and this syntax has followed through to it's derivative languages.

As Bobby Speirs noted, that character was probably originally chosen due to the colon's similar meaning in English grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The colon makes more sense from an English writing point of view, which makes the code easier to read.

Think of it like telling the computer the following:

```
In case the number is 1, you should do these things: 
    Thing 1;
    Thing 2;
    Thing 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

C switch hide a goto to the label equal to the value under test.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.1

> A `case` or `default` label shall appear only in a switch statement.

So, a `case` is a *labeled-statement*.

the prescribed format of a labeled statement is given by

> ```
> labeled-statement:
> identifier : statement
> case constant-expression : statement
> default : statement
> ```

Regarding the *choice* of the `:`, this is in regards to the [assembly syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language), where `:` is used to identify a designated block of statement.